# Parallels of a parameterised curve if not unit speed

Tags: differential-geometry

I just read that if $\gamma$ is a curve given in *unit speed parametrisation* then the parametrisation of a parallel curve is given by

$$ p(s) = \gamma (s) + d n(s)$$

where $n$ is  the unit normal to the curve and $d$ is some scalar.

But, I am wondering if this is a typo: surely, a parallel is always given by this equation even if $\gamma $ is not unit speed?

> Please could someone tell me what is meant here?

Assume $\gamma$ is any curve not necessarily unit speed. Isn't a parallel given by

$p(t) = \gamma (t) + d n(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

I websearched this, and I found a link saying that arclength parametrisation is not necessary. However, if you proved some theorems using the fact that the parametrisation is arclength, these might not hold in general cases. https://books.google.ca/books?id=bwwRg7I02-4C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=parameterized+parallel+curves+arclength&source=bl&ots=P-UKLHnApq&sig=YbuKEyJU9LsFZCkPu6h_kW1KNIY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H0WTVcq9MI-XyATrtK6YBg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=parameterized%20parallel%20curves%20arclength&f=false